# NextJS - new Date cached on server

Tags: typescript, next.js

i am trying to always get a now Date on my server, but it get a cached date.
I use **yarn export** to upload my files on a hosting server via ftp.

My code is:

```
export function MyComponent() {
    const now = new Date();
    return (
        <div>{now.getDate()}/{now.getMonth()+1}/{now.getFullYear()}</div>
    );
}
```

But when i render my component, it always come in a cached value. What am i missing?

- Update, as juliomalves asked:

  ```
    import { useEffect,useState } from 'react';
    export function MyComponent() {
        const [now, setNow] = useState(new Date());
        useEffect(() => {
            setNow(new Date());
        },[])
        return (
            <div>{now.getDate()}/{now.getMonth()+1}/{now.getFullYear()}</div>
        );
    }
  ```

Comment: You're exporting the page as _static_ HTML, the date will always be the same. If you want a dynamic date you'll need to generate it inside a `useEffect` so it runs on the client.

Comment: @juliomalves thanks!!

Comment: hey @juliomalves , it didnt work with useEffect also

Comment: Do you have any caching setup on your server? How long do the pages get cached for?

Comment: have you worked with yarn export? I use hostgator as a server, but the cheap one